# Name of operations on two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose we have two vectors $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$.
I could define the mapping
$$
T: \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}
$$
as follows
$$
T(x,y) = ( x_i+y_j )_{i,j=1}^{n,m},
$$
i.e. $T(x,y)$ is $n\times m$ matrix with elements equal sum of corresponding vectors.
If instead of $x_i+y_j$ one considers $x_i \cdot y_j$ then it is matrix multiplication
of two vectors ($x\cdot y^T$, where $x,y$ are column vectors). But what about sum?

Is that operation known and studied somewhere?

Comment: It's not unlikely that this comes up in tropical geometry (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry), where the "product" is the original addition.

Comment: "Outer sum"? I think that's what the programming language APL called it.

Comment: I've occasionally heard "tensor sum".

Comment: Thank you Tom for direction. 
According to http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Marianne.Johnson/Peter_Butkovic_Beamer%20Manchester%202012%20vs2%20print.pdf

It is indeed tropical product of two vectors $a \otimes b^T$.

Answer (score 1):

It is tropical product of vectors $x$ and $y^T$, i.e. $x \otimes y^T$.

See http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Marianne.Johnson/Peter_Butkovic_Beamer%20Manchester%202012%20vs2%20print.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'd write your operation simply as $x e^T + ey^T$, where $e$ is the vector of all ones. I have never encountered this operation directly studied in a research context (my guess is that it's simply "not interesting enough", since it's a small variation to the common theme of a rank-2 matrix), but I have seen several times the related matrix with elements 
$$
T_{ij}= \frac{1}{x_i - y_j},
$$
which is known as [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).

Comment: There are two vectors of ones $e_m$ and $e_n$ should be above because I assume that $x$ and $y$ are of dimensions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that this operation appears naturally in the context of optimal transport (popped up in https://doi.org/10.1007/s00245-019-09614-w e.g.).